# Rubik's cube with one disoriented corner

Tags: rubiks-cube

I have been trying to solve Rubik's cube using beginner's method provided here:
https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/how-to-solve-the-rubiks-cube-beginners-method/

I ended up with just one last corner which is not oriented properly as shown in the picture. I cannot seem to solve it using R’ D’ R D algorithm, it messes up the whole square when the corner piece gets oriented. Every time I try to solve the cube, it again has just one last corner disoriented. None of the algorithms mention one last corner case. they always talk about 2 or more corners disoriented. I don't understand. Can someone explain whats happening and how to solve it?

[image: one last corner not oriented properly]

Comment: According to @ChrisCudmore's comment to the answer below, it's likely that this is a Speed Cube that accidentally went through a "corner flip" (not a legal Rubik's Cube move), and became unsolvable in that manner. To fix it, flip that corner back: "Essentially, you rotate a layer 45 degrees, and then you can spin one of the corner pieces overhanging the edge in place."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't. Your cube is in an unsolvable state. You must take apart the cube and fix the corner. This happened because one piece was put in improperly. You can either flip one other piece or flip the disoriented piece

Someone pranked you

Comment: Or else Shimano is pranking *us* and e.g. there's an oppositely-twisted corner opposite where it's not visible in the shot.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan touché :^)

Comment: If there's just one last corner then even with a will surely there's no way - can see: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20/why-is-a-single-corner-twist-not-a-valid-position-on-a-rubiks-cube  Maybe to solve it you'd have to pull it apart.

Comment: I am not pranking. I can make a video. I bought this cube online about 2 weeks ago and it was brand new and I sort of remember it was in solved state when it was new. Now I am not so certain. I just found this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1N0reAJmeI0 . Is this prank too?

Comment: @Shimano Yes that is a prank. It was uploaded on April 1st.

Comment: @JacobGoulden Oh...Thanks so much. I wasted few hours trying to solve it :(. Why would the online company sell a messed up cube (now i am not certain whether it was solved or not)

Comment: @Shimano Either it came solved and you accidently rotated a corner piece or it came unsolvable. Either way the cube in the above picture (assuming the other side we can not see is all solved) is unsolvable. If you rotate that corner then the cube will be solvable.

Comment: I remember when Rubik's cubes first came out...  people would "borrow" someone else's cube and swivel one corner for a prank all the time. Also, I imagine that the cube manufacturer is not 100% error free in the manufacturing process, this probably happens from time to time.

Comment: @JacobGoulden. Thanks so much. You saved me so much time. I was trying to follow the video but still didn't work so I posted here. I fixed the cube now :)

Comment: @Shimano Great! Happy cubing :^)

Comment: That's a speed cube (notice the notches in the corner to make it rotate when not completely aligned.)  With these cubes, it's possible to do a "Corner Flip" maneuver. Essentially, you rotate a layer 45 degrees, and then you can spin one of the corner pieces overhanging the edge in place.  It's possible you did this accidentally.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore I also have a speed cube stuck in this configuration. Does your comment above imply that this can be done intentionally to reverse this corner back? Thanks.

Edit: by carefully following Chris's description above I was able to flip my corner back. Hurray!!!

Comment: Thanks @ChrisCudmore!  You saved the day.  I've been struggling with this for too long.  I have a speed cube too.  I had the change the piece and now I can solve it every time.

Comment: I also got the similar puzzle and last corner was not in correct state. As suggested by @JacobGoulden, I rotated last corner with small force and it worked. Corner rotated on the same axis by 45 degree. Fixed my puzzle. Thanks Jacob.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore comment (https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32740/rubiks-cube-with-one-disoriented-corner?newreg=659893e8d14b4e8c9dd51dc6b83c9545#comment98029_32741) was the correct answer for me.