# 2×2×2 rubik's cube corner is twisted!

Tags: rubiks-cube

Is there a way to solve it? If so how?! I have tried remixing it over and over but I haven't solved it yet :/

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If a single corner of a rubik's cube is twisted, it is in an unsolvable state.

The only way to fix it is to take it apart and put it back together again ;)

Comment: A similar question was already asked for a 3x3x3 cube on https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20/why-is-a-single-corner-twist-not-a-valid-position-on-a-rubiks-cube. Explanations of why this state is unsolvable provided on that page are also applicable for a 2x2x2 cube.

Answer (score 3):

This cube can often be fixed by just forcing that corner without complete disassembly. Just twist that corner. Sometimes easier if you move that corner half way between two positions.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of taking it apart, you could also, optionally do one of six things:

1. Take off and rearrange the stickers,
2. Take it back to the store,
3. Tell your friend/family member/distant relative/creepy (probably a stalker) stranger to stop buying you prank gifts,
4. Throw it away,
5. Buy a new one, or
6. Smash it with a sledge hammer out of frustration and anger, throw it away, and THEN buy a new one. I hope this helps you out!
   ;)